# How to replace a dll library for unit testing in C# Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, dll

I have developed a plug-in that uses a dll from a third party (third_party.dll). I have created unit tests for this plug-in, but I cannot run them using the third_party.dll, because it requires the application running.

I have created a dll (my_mock_up.dll) that simulates the API of the third_party.dll

To run the tests copy the source code to the unit test project and replace the occurrences of

```
using ThirdParty.XXX.YYY.ZZZ
```

with

```
using MyMockUp.XXX.YYY.ZZZ
```

but the process is manual and not very efficient. What would be a better approach? Is there a way to run unit tests for a plug-in with the host application running? Does VisualStudio have a functionality or a package for it? I could modify the code of the plug-in to accommodate the unit testing if that is also an option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can hide the implementation details under the interface and use different implementation for production and test code

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski it seems a good approach ... there are many methods in the API but I guess that it only needs to be done once ... I will try, thanks!

Comment: Use a Pre-processor directive : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

Comment: @jdweng that seems a simple enough approach. I will try it first ... thanks for the suggestion and for the link